How to detect a child view not in the view yet due to *ngIf in Angular?
I have an input that's hidden using *ngIf. I'd prefer not to change that as suggested  in a related question. When I click on my component, it take a tiny fraction of a second for the input to come into the view. It's so slight delay, the performance nor perception are inflicted, so I've resolved it by setting off a timer.
@ViewChild("input") input: ElementRef;
@HostListener("click") onClick() {
  this.config.editing = true;
  timer(10).subscribe(a => this.input.nativeElement.focus());
}

Still, it bugs me on a principal level as it's simply bad design. Pragmatic. But poor. So I wonder if there's another way to set the focus as soon as the input becomes in the webpage.

You can look at the Angular component lifecycle and get a callback once your second view is initialized.

Perhaps you can use an autofocus directive like this one - usage - demo

@Pieterjan I propose that you post a reply to be considered as accepted answer. It appears that there's two possible strategies here: lifecycle based and directove based. It'd be good to have both provided so that the future "me" can decide themselves.

You can use the Angular component lifecycle to coordinate actions taken between a parent/child relationship.
Here's a quick example of how it could be done:
parent.html
<child-component #input (initialized)="focusOnInput()"></child-component>

parent.ts
@ViewChild("input") input: ChildComponent;
@HostListener("click") onClick() {
  this.config.editing = true;
  // Will display our input, which then will trigger focus
}

focusOnInput() {
  this.input.focus()
}

child.html
<input ... #input />

child.ts
class ChildComponent implemenets AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('input') input: ElementRef;
  @Output initialized: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter()

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.initialized.emit()
  }

  focus() {
    this.input.nativeElement.focus()
  }
}


That's a nice answer. You overestimated, though, the complexity of my component. There's no child (i.e. the view child is actually ElementRef since it's an actual INPUT tag). Never the less, your answer still apply, with flying colors, n fact, so +1. I'll look up the suggestions based on directives and depending on that, accept an answer. Speaking of that: would you advocate lifecycle before directives in this case?

If you only have a plain input it won't be able to work with Angular's lifecycle, so you do end up with a little more complexity. Personally I prefer the lifecycle approach over directives, but I think either would work just about as well.
